# JMeter execution does not stops when using WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver, jmeter-plugins

I'm using latest JMeter 3.3 to run a latest Selenium WebDriver test, everything seems to be OK,

I only have 1 thread configured with 1 sec ramp up and 1 loop count, however after the webdriver execution is completed, JMeter does not stops the overall test execution and keeps on executing the test for infinity, I'm not sure why is that happening, I'm using chromedriver and all the configuration I have done is as per jmeter documentation, I have also added `WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()` command at the end of my script. Please refer screenshots attached -

[image] [image]

Thread Group -

[image]

I just want as soon as my sample ends, JMeter test execution should also stop.

Comment: Show your thread group definition

Comment: Updated that in the post, please refresh and check again

Comment: Looks ok, if you click stop/shutdown it stops? Any errors in log?

Comment: Even if I click on stop or shutdown, nothing happens and it remains as is, no errors in log it just says stopping thread or shutting down thread thats it, not sure whats happening here

Comment: you have some exception above Stopping in log and it mentions "threadFinished" for seleniumConfig. Did you check what it says?

Comment: I see an error in your screenshot so check jmeter.log for more details and add to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your configuration as per the bug report you made:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61661

You have the below exception occurring which is due to missing jar that contains:

> com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32

So download it with it dependencies put it in jmeter/lib folder.

You can find it here:

- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjna330platformjar.htm
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjna330jar.htm